# How can I get Linked entity of a defect using REST API in QC ALM

Tags: rest, api, alm, hp-quality-center

In QC ALM we have linked entities in every defect. I want to access using REST API. Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

ALM and QC offer an API for accessing defect links. You may find the relevant documentation here: [defect-links Collection](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.60/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html#REST_API_Tech_Preview/REST/defect-links.html%3FTocPath%3DResource%2520Reference%7CEntity%2520Resources%7CDefects%7C_____3)

The described API provides a list of the linked entities which includes their types and ids. Try using the following properties in order to access the entities themselves:

- second-endpoint-id
- second-endpoint-type